# How to require a file with Browserify in the browser?

Tags: browserify

Couldn't find anything in the docs so i am here, how the hack the browserify works? Here is my simple code and the require function do not work in the browser when i do require('file.js');

```
require('browserify')().add([
   'c:\project\bundle.js' , 'c:\project\file.js'
]).bundle((error, bundle) => { });
```

how do i get the file.js on the client side? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So as i figure out the require only works inside the bundle file, so if i do require('./file.js') inside the bundle.js, the require('./file.js') works!